# iOS/Swift - Accessing shared DB using App Groups

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, ios-app-group

I use **App Groups** Capability to share a SQLite DB between two Apps.

Now i want to migrate to Swift from Objective-C.

To **obtain the path of DB**, in Objective-C i've

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *groupContainerURL = [fileMgr containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"<APP_GROUPS_ID>"];

NSString *groupContainerString = [groupContainerURL path];

NSString *sharedDB = [groupContainerString stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbFilename];

const char *dbPath = [sharedDB UTF8String];
```

and it works.

In Swift i've tried this way

```
let groupContainerURL = fileMgr!.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "<APP_GROUPS_ID>")

let groupContainerString = groupContainerURL.path

pathToDatabase = groupContainerString.appending(databaseFileName)
```

and i've declared also

```
let databaseFileName = "<DB_NAME>"

var pathToDatabase: String!

var fileMgr : FileManager!
```

But i've this error, about **Optional Value**

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-07-24 11:25:09.086974 CatchTheData[7941:4022839] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at the start.

Where i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Runtime exception`: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, occurs:

1. when you `unwrap an optional` that contains `nil` **OR**
2. when you use an `implicitly unwrapped optional` without assigning a value to it.

In the following lines:

```
var pathToDatabase: String!
var fileMgr : FileManager!
```

make sure you have assigned value to `pathToDatabase` and `fileMgr` before using them. Since these 2 variables are `implicitly unwrapped optionals`, so in case you use them without assigning values, it will result in `runtime exception` similar to `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.`

```
let groupContainerURL = fileMgr!.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "<APP_GROUPS_ID>")
```

In the above line of code, you are using `fileMgr!`. First of all no need to unwrap it. It is `implicitly unwrapped`. Just make sure `fileMgr` has value so that the app won't crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
let databaseFileName = "<DB_NAME>"

var pathToDatabase: String!

var fileMgr : FileManager? //Your code crashes coz you hv declared fileMgr as non-optional but you hv'nt initialized it.

let AppGroupContainerUrl = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "<APP_GROUPS_ID>")
if let groupContainerURL = AppGroupContainerUrl{
    let groupContainerString = groupContainerURL.path
    pathToDatabase = groupContainerString.appending(databaseFileName)
}
```